# How to compare two arrays for equality?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have not found an answer to the simplest case possible. I know there are lots of questions like that but all of them have a higher degree of complexity. In my case, the arrays are very similar in the following respects:

- the same number of elements
- all the elements are of the same kind,
- the elements consist only of integers 0 and 1

The code I have is:

```
var mearr = [
  [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
  [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
];

for (i=0;i<mearr.length/2;i++) {
    var l = mearr[i];
    var r = mearr[i+3];
    var same = (l == r) ? "Same" : "different";
    console.log(l, r, same);
}
```

I'd assume that the second and fifth elements would return "Same", but they do not.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson It is not a duplicate, since this is totally a different case. The first half part of array is compared with the second half part. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - you are wrong, because you are not reading the code for comprehension.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, I would suggest you to [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and compare as strings!

```js
var mearr = [
  [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
  [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
];

for (i = 0; i < mearr.length / 2; i++) {
  var l = mearr[i].join("");
  var r = mearr[i+(mearr.length/2)].join("");
  var same = (l == r) ? "Same" : "different";
  console.log(l, r, same);
}
```

And yes, yay! It worked:

```
110110 010011 different
111010 111010 Same
111001 100101 different
```

> **Note:** As you said, this works only for an array with binary numbers like this. For this case only!

Comment: Thank you. Having researched it before asking this question, I have seen answers discouraging from converting arrays to strings to do the comparison but, as you say, this would probably be the easiest way in this particular case. Thank you.

Comment: @Wasteland You are right. But yeah, **for this case**, keep in mind. Don't use the solution for anything else. `:)`

Comment: So yes, welcoming all the downvotes. Kindly say the reason please?

Comment: it works for any numbers or strings, not just "binary numbers"...

Comment: @dandavis Yes, it does.